# CSS Apply gradient color to a png logo branding

Tags: css, png, gradient

sorry if it has been already asked but I can't find the solution on how to apply a gradient color to a png logo. Here is the website i'm starting to work on: julienbraida.com.

White Logo is on top left. Client wants apply a gradient color on top of the branding logo and change the gradient color according to pages (to match the theme of the page).

I only was able to apply a color using a filter. But it's not a gradient color and I would need help to do that please.

I've done this:

```
.mobile-header-bar .mobile-branding img {
  filter: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(19deg) saturate(100%);
}
```

But no gradient ... Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Set your image as a background:

> ###### NOTE:
>
> - filters apply to foreground elements, typically images.
> - Gradients are backgrounds and are effectively "under" images.
> - so if you want to apply a `linear-gradient` to an `img` you have to overlay the `<img>` with another element with a greater z-index

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bgImageOnly {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300') no-repeat;
}

.bgImgFilter {
  filter: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(19deg) saturate(100%);
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300') no-repeat;
}

.bgImgGradient {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 121, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(250, 0, 255, .5) 54%, rgba(126, 0, 255, .5) 100%), url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300') no-repeat;
  ;
}



div.logos{
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

div.logos img{
  height: 80px;
  width: 150px;
}


img{
  padding: 20px 0px; 
}
.yourFilterParameters{
  filter: brightness(1) invert(0) drop-shadow(0 1px 1px rgba(41, 55, 90, .4));
}

.somethingMoreVisible {
  filter: brightness(70%) invert(30%) drop-shadow(4px 2px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75))
}

div.gradientOverlay{
  height: 80px;
  width: 150px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

div.gradientOverlay::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 80px;
  width: 150px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 121, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(250, 0, 255, .5) 54%, rgba(126, 0, 255, .5) 100%);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="bgImageOnly"></div>
<div class="bgImgFilter"></div>
<div class="bgImgGradient"></div>
<hr>
<div class="logos">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300"
       class="yourFilterParameters">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300"
       class="somethingMoreVisible">
  <div class="gradientOverlay">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300">
  </div>
</div>
```

Kiwi bird SVG (c)Chris Coyer @ CSS-Tricks.com: see [Using SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)

```css
.logo {
  width: 122px;
  height: 100px;
}

.kiwi {
  fill: url(#lgrad);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="612px" height="502.174px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174" enable-background="new 0 65.326 612 502.174" xml:space="preserve"
  class="logo">
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="lgrad" x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255, 121, 0);stop-opacity:.5" />
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(250, 0, 255);stop-opacity:.5" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(126,0,155);stop-opacity:.5" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

<ellipse class="ground" cx="283.5" cy="487.5" rx="259" ry="80"/>
<path class="kiwi" d="M210.333,65.331C104.367,66.105-12.349,150.637,1.056,276.449c4.303,40.393,18.533,63.704,52.171,79.03
  c36.307,16.544,57.022,54.556,50.406,112.954c-9.935,4.88-17.405,11.031-19.132,20.015c7.531-0.17,14.943-0.312,22.59,4.341
  c20.333,12.375,31.296,27.363,42.979,51.72c1.714,3.572,8.192,2.849,8.312-3.078c0.17-8.467-1.856-17.454-5.226-26.933
  c-2.955-8.313,3.059-7.985,6.917-6.106c6.399,3.115,16.334,9.43,30.39,13.098c5.392,1.407,5.995-3.877,5.224-6.991
  c-1.864-7.522-11.009-10.862-24.519-19.229c-4.82-2.984-0.927-9.736,5.168-8.351l20.234,2.415c3.359,0.763,4.555-6.114,0.882-7.875
  c-14.198-6.804-28.897-10.098-53.864-7.799c-11.617-29.265-29.811-61.617-15.674-81.681c12.639-17.938,31.216-20.74,39.147,43.489
  c-5.002,3.107-11.215,5.031-11.332,13.024c7.201-2.845,11.207-1.399,14.791,0c17.912,6.998,35.462,21.826,52.982,37.309
  c3.739,3.303,8.413-1.718,6.991-6.034c-2.138-6.494-8.053-10.659-14.791-20.016c-3.239-4.495,5.03-7.045,10.886-6.876
  c13.849,0.396,22.886,8.268,35.177,11.218c4.483,1.076,9.741-1.964,6.917-6.917c-3.472-6.085-13.015-9.124-19.18-13.413
  c-4.357-3.029-3.025-7.132,2.697-6.602c3.905,0.361,8.478,2.271,13.908,1.767c9.946-0.925,7.717-7.169-0.883-9.566
  c-19.036-5.304-39.891-6.311-61.665-5.225c-43.837-8.358-31.554-84.887,0-90.363c29.571-5.132,62.966-13.339,99.928-32.156
  c32.668-5.429,64.835-12.446,92.939-33.85c48.106-14.469,111.903,16.113,204.241,149.695c3.926,5.681,15.819,9.94,9.524-6.351
  c-15.893-41.125-68.176-93.328-92.13-132.085c-24.581-39.774-14.34-61.243-39.957-91.247
  c-21.326-24.978-47.502-25.803-77.339-17.365c-23.461,6.634-39.234-7.117-52.98-31.273C318.42,87.525,265.838,64.927,210.333,65.331
  z M445.731,203.01c6.12,0,11.112,4.919,11.112,11.038c0,6.119-4.994,11.111-11.112,11.111s-11.038-4.994-11.038-11.111
  C434.693,207.929,439.613,203.01,445.731,203.01z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply @fnostro! Unfortunately, I already tried this... But it doesn't give me a "gradient color" but a flat uniform color instead of the logo's white basic color as you can see on the page initially. The client would like a gradient color on top of the logo, like an overlay or a mask. For e.g. apply that type of gradient color: 
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,121,0,1) 0%, rgba(250,0,255,1) 54%, rgba(126,0,255,1) 100%);
But I don't see how to do that... Any clue ? Thanks again

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer. NB: you should not use opacity 1, otherwise you cannot see the image.

Comment: Thanks again but it doesn't work either... try it, enter in dev mode to explore the website content and try to apply your code. I'd like to show you with a screenshot I've done

Comment: Here is where to apply the CSS: .page-id-12840 .mobile-branding > a, .mobile-branding > img {
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
  filter: brightness(1) invert(0) drop-shadow(0 1px 1px rgba(41, 55, 90, .4));
 -webkit-filter: brightness(1) invert(0) drop-shadow(0 1px 1px rgba(41, 55, 90, .4));
}

Comment: Here is the link to the screenshot after applying your code: https://paste.pics/163a2aa24a446c839bdf8beb141498b0

Comment: filters apply to foreground elements, typically images. Gradients, linear or otherwise, are backgrounds and are effectively "under" images. See update above.

Comment: It doesn't work. See screenshot below. It doesn't fit the logo, only make a square on top of it. I'm so sorry really to make you loose your time for me. Thanks for your help deeply. I think I'm not good enough in CSS to achieve that goal. I'm not a dev only a web designer. Maybe it would be easier for me to photoshop the logo applying some gradient on it and see how to apply this modified logo with gradient according to the page instead of the initial logo. https://paste.pics/174d636d7d62ba8326f6d19c5bff912d

Comment: If you want the gradient over _only_ the logo then yes. Look into using CSS with SVG. You can save your logo to an SVG file and use it directly on you page and style it with css.

Comment: Added one more update using SVG.

Comment: SVG, good point! Thanks @fnostro :) I'll try to convert the logo in SVG and style it with CSS.

Comment: By the way and cause you're a pro, i've got one more question for u: there is a main image on each website pages, an "hero" landing image. It's a 16:9 ratio image, looks great on desktop. But on mobile, portrait viewport specifically, the image doesn't look great: it is zoomed, not centered, clearly not optimized for this view. So I'd like to display another image I will prepare, especially redesigned and optimized for portrait viewport. Using CSS, how can I display one image or another according to the device viewport? Thanks again for your help! ;)

Comment: Look into Media Queries. This allows you to use the same css class names with different definitions. eg viewports for desktop vs laptop vs tablet vs phone can be defined to hold images designed for their specific view port.  Alternatively look into implementing [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) or similar.  Specificially this: [Responsive Images](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/images/)